# how use oauth2 in nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am developing a website with nuxtjs framework and using oauth2 authentication flow.

so as you know I have to save refreshToken in localstorage for some security things and it's not safe to save it in cookie.
after one hour the accessToken expires and I should request to server for new accessToken by refreshtoken.

so when the request is from client side, every things looks fine and works perfectly.but the problem is when user reload the page, the request is sent by nuxt server side (nodejs) and there is no way to access localstorage for getting refeshtoken.

so what should I do?
what is the best way for use oauth2 in nuxtjs?

Comment: do you have some sample repo